# Guidance with jQuery form plugin please

Tags: jquery

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a form on my website which I would like to submit with AJAX. I found the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) but I have no idea where to start to set it up. For some reason the action="" attribute? in my form HTML is empty (I didn't set up the form myself) Do I need to create a php file?

If someone could outline for me the steps needed to set this up that would be fantastic

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_info"/>
    {foreach from=$form_fields item=form_field}
        {if $show_mailing_flag==0 && $form_field.id=="sendmail"}
        {elseif $form_field.id=="video"}
            <fieldset>
                <div class="inputName">[[$form_field.caption]]</div>
                <div class="inputReq">&nbsp;{if $form_field.is_required}*{/if}</div>
                <div class="inputField">{input property=$form_field.id template="video_profile.tpl"}</div>
            </fieldset>
        {else}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inputName">[[$form_field.caption]]</div>
            <div class="inputReq">&nbsp;{if $form_field.is_required}*{/if}</div>
            <div class="inputField">{input property=$form_field.id}</div>
        </fieldset>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inputName">
                {if $acl->isAllowed('delete_user_profile')}
                    <input type="button" value="[[Delete profile:raw]]" class="button" onclick="{literal}if(confirm('{/literal}[[Are you sure you want to delete your account?:raw]]{literal}')) {location.href='?action=delete_profile'}{/literal}" />
                {/if}
            </div>
            <div class="inputReq">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="inputField"><input type="submit" value="[[Save:raw]]" class="button" /></div>
        </fieldset>
{/if}
```

PS should there be a  tag at the end? Seems to work fine without it at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form action is blank, it submits to itself (form.php submits to form.php).

With AJAX, the form action shouldn't matter unless the request's destination is specified by the action attribute (which would work well for graceful degradation).

As far as getting the form data to submit through an asynchronous request, you could use jQuery's [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. So,

1. Capture the form's submit event.
2. Stop the default form submission event by calling *e.preventDefault()*
3. Serialize the form data with .serialize()
4. Make an AJAX request using jquery's [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.
5. Based on the response from the AJAX request, display a result to the user

Comment: So just to confirm, this doesn't use the plugin? Uses the existing form.php?

Comment: It's possible that it *could* be using the plugin, but there's no way to know based on what you posted.